# How to execute Javascript in a bash script?

Tags: javascript, node.js, bash, output, readfile

I have made a bash script that reads a file line by line and returns what is on that line, though what I want to do is have that bash script run a JS function with what exists in that file and return to the user running the script the output of that JS function.

How can I complete that? I am using a node.js backend and this what my script currently looks like.

```
#!/bin/bash
while IFS='' read -r line || [[ -n "$line" ]]; do
    echo "Text read from file: $line"
done < "$1"
```

for example if my file contains two lines that are 2 and 4 and I have a JS file that multiplies by 2 how can I get this bash script to return 4 and 8 by running that method on each line.

Comment: Why not just do it all from node to begin with? It has an `fs` module that can read files ...

Comment: I am doing this as a challenge from a colleague and this was a requirement, one that I've been hung up on.

Comment: You could pipe the text to `node`. For example if you do `echo 'console.log("test")' | /usr/bin/node` (or whatever your path to node is) it would output 'test'. Here's an example of getting the output as well: `result=\`echo 'console.log("test")' | /usr/bin/node\`;
echo $result`